# If condition in a loop is not met, show a msg box

Tags: excel, vba

I'm am trying to find out how I can show a messagebox if the first if statement is not met. If you delete the else statement it does what it should do, put the values in the correct cells. But if the else statement is added it will show the messagebox immediately.

```
Sub Column_Names2()
Dim c
For Each c In Range("A1:Z1").Cells
    If c = "" Then
        c.Value = "Accounting Number"
        c.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Receipt/Invoice"
        c.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Proccesed"
    Else: MsgBox "Could not find empty cell"
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You probably have cells with value in them first.

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Okay... welll that's your reason...? You're going through each column... I'll post an answer to illustrate.

Comment: Ooh ok. I thought A1:Z1 means its only going like this A1,B1,C1,D1,E1 etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as you said in the comments, you have blank stills first (meaning to the left). You are also exiting the loop after this `else` condition is met. Ultimately you need to finish the loop before you want to say none have been found.

So try something like this. I didn't test but I suspect it will work for you.

```
Sub Column_Names2()
    Const rangeOfCells = "A1:Z1"
    Dim c As Range, foundBlankCell As Boolean
    
    For Each c In Range(rangeOfCells).Cells
        If c.Value = "" Then
            foundBlankCell = True
            c.Value = "Accounting Number"
            c.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Receipt/Invoice"
            c.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Proccesed"
            Exit For '<--- assuming you want the check of columns to end
        End If
    Next
    
    If Not foundBlankCell Then MsgBox "Could not find empty cell"
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry... there was an issue with the last line I just corrected it

Comment: Wait, I'm guessing you want the loop to end once it finds a blank cell?

Comment: I also want it to stop if the empty cell is found. Where should you put exit for?

Answer (score 0):

probably use it like this

```
Sub Column_Names2()
Dim c
For Each c In Range("A1:Z1").Cells
    If c = "" Then
        c.Value = "Accounting Number"
        c.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Receipt/Invoice"
        c.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Proccesed"
    ElseIF c <> "" Then 'just inverse your other condition
     MsgBox "Could not find empty cell"
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I am still only getting the message box unfortunately

Comment: @brugon, this seems functionally the same code...? inverse other condition as you describe is thsame as 'else'?

Comment: You are right @pgSystemTester sorry !